# Can ERC721 NFT issuer modify onchain metadata after selling?

Tags: nft

I mint an ERC721 NFT and transfer the token to another address.

Do I, as the original issuer, still have privileges to change any token properties?

If yes, can these 'issuer privileges' be transferred to another address?

Comment: It depends on the contract. Some contracts won't allow modifications, some only allow the owner to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes and no. If you use the original ERC721 you can't modify it because it's immutable. So once it's minted you can't change it in any way.

But if you modify the ERC721 standard you could introduce this functionality.